# How do I expose custom init implememntation to interface using objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I simpley defined Swift protocol like this:

```
@objc protocol MobileKeyable {
   var assaAbloyLockServiceCode: Int { get }
}
```

Then I use it in my objective-c class:

```
- (id)initWithComposition: (id<MobileKeyable>)composition {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _lockServiceCodes = @[@([composition assaAbloyLockServiceCode])];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then I would like to initialize that controller in Swift like this:

```
let composition = //here MobileKeyable
MobileKeysController(composition: composition)
```

So I need to expose that initializer to objective-c interface:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
@interface MobileKeysController : NSObject <MobileKeysManagerDelegate>
- (instancetype) initWithComposition: (id<MobileKeyable>)composition;
@end
```

but here I have an error: `MyProject-Swift.h file not found`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Xcode tries to avoid some cycling... just assumption. Try instead forward declaration

```c
@protocol MobileKeyable;

@interface MobileKeysController : NSObject <MobileKeysManagerDelegate>
- (instancetype) initWithComposition: (id<MobileKeyable>)composition;
@end
```